# How to get all files from folder and subfolder in magento 2

Tags: filesystems, magento2, getfiles

I made a module for uploading images in frontend. Magento 2 saves files in a special way. For example:

- **uploading file** - `file.png`,
- **path to file** - `pub/media/[module_folder]/f/i/file.png`.

How to get all files from `[module_folder]`?

[image]

Comment: Get them how? In what system/language? In what format?

Comment: I want to get names and paths of all file in folder and subfolder.
Magento 2, PHP

Answer (score 7):

Try the below, use the directorylist class to get the path, and the file class to read the directory :D

```
public  function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\DirectoryList $directoryList,
    \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Driver\File $driverFile,
    LoggerInterface $logger)
{
    $this->directoryList =$directoryList;
    $this->driverFile = $driverFile;
    $this->logger = $logger;
}

public function getAllFiles($path = '/import/') {
    $paths = [];
    try {
        //get the base folder path you want to scan (replace var with pub / media or any other core folder)
        $path = $this->directoryList->getPath('var') . $path;
        //read just that single directory
        $paths =  $this->driverFile->readDirectory($path);
        //read all folders
        $paths =  $this->driverFile->readDirectoryRecursively($path);
    } catch (FileSystemException $e) {
        $this->logger->error($e->getMessage());
    }

    return $paths;
}
```